# How to parse datetime with timezone, but no T or nanoseconds

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to parse a datetime string in the following format:

```
2019-02-22 19:29:43+00:00
```

I'm following this guide:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

This particular row seems to be the timestamp string that I'm trying to parse for:

```
Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;
```

Here is what I created, given that guide:

```
String input = "2019-02-22 19:29:43+00:00";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX");
LocalDateTime parsed = LocalDateTime.parse(input, formatter);
```

But I get this error:

```
 java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-02-22 19:29:43+00:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

• **Wrong class**: `OffsetDateTime`, not `LocalDateTime`.

• **Replace SPACE** with `T` for standard format used by default.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse(               // Do NOT use `LocalDateTime` class, use `OffsetDateTime` because your input has an offset-from-UTC. 
    "2019-02-22 19:29:43+00:00"
    .replace( " " , "T" )           // Replace SPACE in middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601 standard format.
)                                   // Returns a `OffsetDateTime`.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com.](https://ideone.com/WrzvFs)

## Wrong type

Your input string includes an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

But you are trying to parse that as a [`LocalDateTime`.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) A `LocalDateTime` has no concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) because it does *not* represent a moment. So, [square peg, round hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole). You are discarding valuable information.

Instead you should be parsing as a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

## ISO 8601

Your input string is nearly in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. To comply fully, simply replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2019-02-22 19:29:43+00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

The ISO 8601 formats are used by default by the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX`. This should solve your problem.

> **Offset X and x:**
>
> One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as '+0130'.
>
> Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'.
>
> Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'.
>
> Four letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, without a colon, such as '+013015'.
>
> Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as '+01:30:15'.
>
> Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException.

From the description below the table: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

**EDIT:**

If you want to format dates with that pattern and want the same output string you should use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssxxx` instead (see Andreas' comment below).

Comment: Wow. I think I tried XX:XX. Didn't quite understand that. This works. Thank you.

Comment: Since question example shows `+00:00`, it should be 'xxx', not 'XXX', since javadoc states: *"Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero"*. --- For *parsing*, it makes no difference, but if OP also want to *format* using this pattern, it should be fixed.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for that info, I edited my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Working code to solve this problem is below

```
public class Demo {
public static void jodaTimeStuff(String dateString, DateTimeZone dtz) {
    System.out.println(StringUtils.leftPad(dateString, 29, " ") + "\t------->\t" + DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ").parseDateTime(dateString).toDateTime(dtz));
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    jodaTimeStuff("2019-02-22 19:29:43+00:00", DateTimeZone.UTC);
    jodaTimeStuff("2019-02-22 19:29:43+00:00", DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")));
}
```

}

Some dependencies used in the sample code (one is just for formatting and another one is for joda:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

> Dua me yaad rakhna (Please remember me in your prayers)